# Bar Chart in Angular 6

Tags: angular

Am trying to use bar chart in angular 6 but it is not working. I have tried several things such as jqx chart, prime faces and so on but its not working. I have installed it through angular cli.

Comment: please be specific on your question. For example, what is not working, what is the error and what exactly you need.

Comment: Please include the relevant code that you've tried

Comment: This is the link i used: https://www.jqwidgets.com/angular/angular-chart/#https://www.jqwidgets.com/angular/angular-chart/angular-chart-columnlocaldata.htm

Comment: The script: <script src="../aot/chart_columnlocaldata.bundle.js"></script>

Comment: You can leverage the amazing d3 library. Run command 'npm install d3 @types/d3' and you should be good to go. Please refer this link for a basic bar chart example https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304. Not to mention it's highly customisable.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this with chart.js.

Step to install chart.js library:

- npm install chart.js --save

Next, you have to import the module in your Component:

- import { Chart } from 'chart.js';

Finally according to your data you can create your graphs.

Let us consider an example for showing a bar graph for "Monthly Registered Users".

First, create canvas element in your component template as shown below:

```
<canvas id="lineCharts"></canvas>
```

Now on your component.ts file, create a function lets say showChart(); as shown below:

```
  showChart() {
    this.chart = new Chart('lineCharts', {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
      labels: this.month_name, // your labels array
      datasets: [
        {
          label: '# user count',
          data: this.user_count, // your data array
          backgroundColor: [
           'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
           'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
           'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
           'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
           'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
           'rgba(230, 25, 75, 1)',
           'rgba(60, 180, 75, 1)',
           'rgba(245, 130, 48, 1)',
           'rgba(145, 30, 180, 1)',
           'rgba(210, 245, 60, 1)',
           'rgba(0, 128, 128, 1)',
           'rgba(128, 0, 0, 1)'

          ],
          fill:true,
          lineTension:0.2,
          borderWidth: 1
        }
      ]
      },
      options: {
        responsive: true,
        title: {
        text:"Monthly Users Graph",
        display:true
        },
        scales: {
          yAxes:[{
            ticks:{
              beginAtZero:true
            }
          }]
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Where this.month_name is a labels array and this.user_count is a data array. You should mention your labels and data array accordingly.

Last you have to call this showChart() function on ngOnInit() method as shown below:

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.showChart();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bar chart from PrimeNG.
Something like this: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/chart/bar

Steps to use PrimeNG

1. npm install primeng --save
   npm install primeicons --save
2. Add css and js in your angular.json file like below

```
"styles": [
    "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css",
    "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
    "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
    //...
],
```

3. Follow PrimeNg example